# Center text over fluid images

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have several fluid images that I want to float and stack up next to each other. For example I have the img-div width set to 50% which stacks two images in each row. The images also increase in size depending on browser size. At the same time I want to be able to put a text over the middle of each image that floats around and stays in the center of the images. My problem is the text not centering. When I set img as absolute it centers but the stacking gets messed up.

Any idea how I can do this via CSS only?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- image1 -->
    <div class="img-div">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" />
        <div class="txt-div">
          <p>Some text goes here!</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- image2 -->
    <div class="img-div">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" />
        <div class="txt-div">
          <p>Another text.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- image3 -->
    <div class="img-div">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/image3.jpg" />
        <div class="txt-div">
          <p>Some more text.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- image4 -->
    <div class="img-div">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" />
        <div class="txt-div">
          <p>Last text.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.img-div {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;

  a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  a:before {
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }

  .txt-div {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: medium;

    p {
      padding: 0; 
      margin:0;
    }

  }

  img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: A JSfiddle would be useful but positioning the `p` absolutely would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it :)

use `position:relative/ absolute` to draw your text-container over the image, and within use the pseudo `:before` and `vertical-align` technique to center your `<p>`.

```
.img-div {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.img-div img {
  width:100%;
}
a {
  text-align: center;    
}
.txt-div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1;
}
.txt-div:before {
  content:'';
  padding-top:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
}
.txt-div p {
  max-width:95%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/Cxkqf

Answer (score 0):

remove the div around the `p` and set `position:absolute;` to the `p` set the `img` to `position:relative;` the `p` will now go over the `img`, if I'm correct. set `text-align:center;` to `p` to get it centered. (sometimes it might be good to `width:100%;` the `p` too)

Comment: Ok good answer, I'm getting close! Now the issue is I'd have to set top:50% and left:50% to center the p but what you get is the top left corner of the p starting at the center. I want to see the center of the p box pinned to the center. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS background images to place each image in a dynamically sized div, then simply float the divs and they will fill in whatever space without altering position of the block level elements. In this case each div would get a unique id according to the image it would contain and the urls for your images would be a background image for the div. The only drawback to this that I can see is that if images were disabled you would not get alt text, but your divs would remain the specified size. and in their correct position.